# I want to display document ids of collection in future builder but i got error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the code in which i want to display documents ids from cloud firestore but i got error.

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: db.collection('/Exam').get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot) {
    if (asyncSnapshot.hasError)
      return Text("Error: ${asyncSnapshot.error}");
    if (!asyncSnapshot.hasData)
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      isExpanded: true,
      items: asyncSnapshot.data!.docs
          .map(
            (snap) => DropdownMenuItem(
              value: snap.id,
              child: Text(
                snap.id.toString(),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      value: _selectedexam,
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedexam = newValue!;
          _selectedsemester = null;
          print(_selectedexam);
        });
      },
    );
  }),
```

[image: here is my error picture]

Comment: Use a `StreamBuilder` or `FutureBuilder` to get the documents from the collection and then Create the `DropdownButton` with the snapshots. See this example of a DropdownButton [Example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

Comment: Check my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the Generic type to the `map<T>()` method:

```dart
asyncSnapshot.data!.docs
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
            (snap) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: snap.id,
              child: Text(
                snap.id.toString(),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
```